# sum of listbox is not showing the comma

Tags: excel, vba, formatting, numbers

I am trying to sum the total in a column form a Listbox
I noticed if I use point, the calculation is not correct. After using comma calculation was correct, but the total is calculated via VBA and is not showing correctly. The result is that the sum of that column is not correctly shown.
example
2,16 +
4,16
is calculated as 632. but is should be 6,32
I provided the code I used. I am not an expert neither a programmer. So a little help of you guys is welcome.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
Dim Mysum As Double
Dim Cnt As Long
Mysum = 0

Sheet1.Activate
ListBox1.ColumnWidths = "140;95;50;55;55;65;90"         'Column Widths Of 
Listbox
ListBox1.ColumnCount = 7                                                        
'Column Count Of Listbox
ListBox1.List = Sheet1.Range("A2:G" & Sheet1.Cells(Rows.count, 
1).End(xlUp).Row).Value

With ListBox1
For r = 0 To .ListCount - 1
Cnt = Cnt + 1
Mysum = Mysum + .List(r, 4)
Next r
End With
TextBox10.Value = Mysum
TextBox12.Value = Cnt


With ComboBox1
.AddItem "Item Name"
.AddItem "Barcode"
.AddItem "Location"
End With
With ComboBox2
.AddItem "="
.AddItem "<"
.AddItem ">"
End With
TextBox9.Value = ListBox1.ListCount
End Sub
```

Comment: Pl be little be more elaborate on the way you want to sum and the example provided. Do you want to sum numerically then 16+4 would be 20, if want to concatenate the strings then it would be 164 or 16,4 (with comma as separator).

Comment: Thanks for replying. I have a column price and column qty. And a column with total. I wanted to see the total of all values in the total column in the userform. The calculations are made direct from the userform. So no formulas in my Excel sheet

Answer (score 0):

You import text values into your ListBox, I think it's better to import values/doubles directly.

but try:

```
Mysum = Mysum + Replace(.List(r, 4), ".", ",")
```

or (only when it's possible to evaluate to a number):

```
Mysum = Mysum + Application.Evaluate(.List(r, 4))
```